# Unable to access private file?

Tags: 8, media

I had this issue before, and last time the problem was that node was unpublished. The private file became accessible when the node was published.

This time, however, I'm not using a node. I'm just using Drupals file manage system to store my own files for my own custom module. SO I generated a url for an image file like so:

```
$imageFile = file_load($userInput['fid']);
$style = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('image_style')->load('thumbnail');
$url = $style->buildUrl($imageFile->getFileUri());
```

If I print out the URL, I get:

```
http://localhost/system/files/styles/thumbnail/private/cfiles/test.png?itok=Le14o4Zs
```

But when I access that, i get "access denied".

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Drupal 8, private file permissions by default are given according to the entity to which they are attached. If the user has permission to view the entity, they will have permission to view the file.

If you are not attaching the file to an entity, then you will need to implement [hook_file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_file_download/8.6.x), where you will determine whether or not the user has permission to access the file, and return a value accordingly. Currently, because you have no implemented this, access is denied by default.

Note that this hook can be implemented even when the file is attached to an entity to provide additional access checks and/or additional headers.

Answer (score 2):

Another nice way to negotiate file access according some more complex conditions than `hook_file_download($uri)` allows you to check for, is to implement [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access/8.2.x) for the file entity and check if the `$operation` equals `'download'` like in the snippet below. There you also have access to the actual `$file` entity.

```php
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;
use Drupal\file\FileInterface;

/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_access().
 */
function MYMODULE_file_access(FileInterface $file, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
  if ($operation === 'download') {
    // Do access stuff ...
    // ...
    // ...
  }
  // No opinion.
  return AccessResult::neutral();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Jaypan said, If you are not attaching the file to an entity, then you will need to implement [hook_file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21file.api.php/function/hook_file_download/8.6.x), where you will determine whether or not the user has permission to access the file.

Here is a code example that can help :

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_download().
 */
function mymodule_file_download($uri) {
  // Check if the file is private.
  if (StreamWrapperManager::getScheme($uri) == 'private') {

    // Exclude file not in location.
    if (strpos($uri, '/location/') === false) {
      return NULL;
    }

    $account = Drupal::currentUser();
    $user_roles = $account->getRoles();

    // Check if user has the authorized role.
    if (in_array('administrator', $user_roles)
      || in_array('country_administrator', $user_roles)
      || in_array('super_administrator', $user_roles)) {
      return ['Content-disposition' => 'attachment'];
    }
  }

  return NULL;
}
```